# Having trouble accessing content of a nested list item

Tags: r, list

```
> str(docs[200])
List of 1
 $ character(0):List of 2
  ..$ content: chr "I like cats"
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2016-06-22 08:36:04"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ language     : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "VCorpus" "Corpus"
```

How do I create a variable for the content of contents?

Tried:

```
a <- docs[200]$content
```

Does not work.

Tried:

```
a <- docs[[200]]
```

Does not work

Tried:

```
a <- docs[[200]][1]
```

Does not work.

How can I create a variable for "I like cats", what appears to be the second item in the list `docs[200]`

Comment: Try `docs[[200]][[1]]$content`.  It is better to use `dput` to show the structure of a small data.

Comment: Worked after removing double braces on second item: docs[[200]][1]$content
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a nested list, we can do

```
v1 <- docs[[200]][1]$content
v1
#[1] "I like cats"
```